# Android Studio startup is taking long

Tags: java, android, xml

I installed Android Studio, Created a project name and it gives me a popup with a title "Building Project name Gradle project info" and it contains "Gradle: Downloading URL" and its taking too, I mean too long .. does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Android studio is fast as hell on my macbook pro with 8 gb ram, ssd and i5 cpu. But is very slow on my ubuntu machine with i5, 6 gb ram and normal hdd.

Comment: I had and older laptop, it worked fine, not in the good laptop that I have

Comment: Use Eclipse. LibGDX is better performance on Android anyway for most things.

Comment: I had many problems with eclipse, I wish they're gone away!

Comment: Sa77a they are gone and tons of more have come .

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the default allocation of ram to the emulator is too high, and it's testing it. Check out the emulators and make sure the memory it's trying to use is reasonable. Anything over one gig makes my computer run like crap, and I have 8g ram.

Comment: Why do people use emulators at all? I just plug my phone in... the emulator is so slow that compared to just plugging in the phone it seems totally useless!

Comment: So you don't have to plug stuff in. If you have a fast computer it's much easier to just use an emulator. You can also run tests on every Android device in existence. Many of them will run apps differently, so it's good to test.

Comment: I have a very fast computer and the emulator takes forever compared to my phone!(Like at least 10 times faster is the phone...) I don't see how it can be easier when you have to charge your phone anyway and as soon as it loads the program you can unplug it if you don't want debugging log. The only time the emulator makes sense to me I guess is to test a device you do not have.

Comment: In downloading Gradle (where it took ages) the URL (as you can see in red) is not all there, so Im manually try to figure out what it is, 4.2.1 or 4.2.2? look at the picture.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/erIwy.png

Answer (score 0):

When you create the first project, it needs to download the correct version of Gradle, as well as the Android Gradle plugin and various dependencies -- these aren't part of the default installation. How long it takes depends on your network connection. Once that stuff is downloaded, subsequent builds should be much faster.