# Android Emulator startup time is too long

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, startup, haxm

I am using Android Studio with Intel HAXM. The problem is that the Android emulator takes too long to load and once it is loaded it is slow despite the Intel HAXM installation.

I just referred this question and below were my results

[Android Studio startup is taking long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094928/android-studio-startup-is-taking-long)

Result: The emulator is still slow even after loading it for a couple of times.

Intel HAXM configuration

Memory allocated: 1.9 GB(this is the max size as specified during the installation)

Status: Intel HAXM is working.

Android Studio

AVD Details

API Level:19

Android Version: 4.4.2

Please see the screenshot

[image]

System Configuration
Core i3 2nd gen
4 GB RAM

Please let me know if further details are needed.

Comment: Reason for downvote so that I can improve my question a bit more ?

Comment: Just use Genymotion dude.

Comment: @Daan Thank you I have installed and is very fast than stock emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem to you in the past, but its just down to your processor (i3) as it cant handle the emulator that well, you can debug/run your app on to an android phone or tablet.  If you have either of these to hand you need to go to RUN ---> EDIT CONFIGURATIONS and change the target devices to 'USB device'.  On the phone/ tablet you need to go in to developer options and turn on USB debugging, if this doesn't work check to see if you have the phones/tablets drivers installed.  There are plenty of tutorials on youtube. Good Luck! :)